# Postgres "UPDATE FROM VALUES" with different number of nullable columns?

Tags: postgresql

`values()` requires each row to have the same number of columns. Sometimes, I want to update different columns for different rows. If the columns weren't nullable, I could do something like:

```
update test set
  foo = coalesce(t.foo, foo),
  bar = coalesce(t.bar, bar)
from (values
  (1, 'foo val', null),
  (2, null, 'bar val')  
) as t(id, foo, bar) 
where t.id = test.id;
```

However, if the columns are nullable, this wouldn't work. Is there a way to make this work for nullable columns?

Comment: Have you tried it in on nullable column? `coalesce(null, null)` will return `NULL`. So if `t.foo` is `NULL` and the `foo` value is `NULL` you would be setting `foo=NULL`, which is what you want. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It wouldn't work if the value used to be non-null, but I want to update it to null

Comment: Hmm, yeah that is not going to work.

Comment: `where t.id = test.id;` -->> `where t.id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM test.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pick some special value which is valid for the type, but will never actually be used in your table.  Then that value could represent "keep old value". If not, then you probably need more columns.

```
update test set
  foo = case when not set_foo_null then coalesce(t.foo, test.foo) end,
  bar = case when not set_bar_null then coalesce(t.bar, test.bar) end
from (values
  (1, 'foo val', null, false, true),
  (2, null, 'bar val', false, false)  
) as t(id, foo, bar, set_foo_null, set_bar_null) 
where t.id = test.id;
```

Of course there are many other ways to formulate, maybe better would be to name the bool "keep_old_foo" then `foo = case when keep_old_foo then test.foo else t.foo end`